# Как добавить data-attribute в option

Tags: javascript

Сейчас опции создаются циклом:

```
var options = JSON.parse(data);
var select = document.getElementById('select_chanel');
options.forEach(function (option, i) {
select.options[i] = new Option(option.name, option.externalId);
});
```

К в этом же цикле сделать добавление "data-attribute". Например data-id, который будет равен option.externalId

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Видимо так:

```
select.options[i].setAttribute(name, value);
```

где `name` будет "data-id"

либо так

```
select.options[i].dataset[name] = value;
```

где `name` будет просто "id"

Comment: то, что надо! спасибо